# How can I make a ponytail?

Tags: particles, hair

I am trying to make a ponytail, particularly one that is fastened high up on the back of the head. I want it to look realistic, but attempting to animate a "hairbob" sliding over it and moving into position has only worked until it was getting close to the right size, when half the hair popped through it. Is there any particular way to fix this besides jacking up the basic particle settings? Some kind of hair particle constraint?

Edit: This is what I want it to be shaped like, though I want movable hair. I would prefer something that looks realistic (why do women in space wear shiny leotards?): [image: Samus Aran Model]

Comment: Please add a reference image of what you want to get.

Comment: @susu Sigh. I’m still stuck on this, and I like that style a lot.

Comment: Does this help you? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209220/how-do-i-distribute-hair-particles-evenly-using-guiding-curves-ponytail-with-h

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need! I may want to mark this question as a duplicate…