# How do I distribute hair particles evenly using guiding curves? (Ponytail with Hair Dynamics)

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

[image: screenshot of the ponytail]

I tried increasing the steps under both the viewport and render tab, messing with the guiding curves, and amplification under the Children tab. No method I've tried so far has been able to simultaneously keep the ponytail form and cover my character's entire head with hair. In order to get the shape I wanted, I made the two different particles systems and connected both systems under one guiding curve.

[image: weight painting map]

Hair Dynamics are enabled for the ponytail and the main hair, with interpolated children.

Comment: can you add an image of what you have done? Have you used weight painting? What type of children: simple or interpolated?

Comment: Yes I have weight painted, here is what that looks like:https://youtu.be/NHda6hHRY1Q And here is the most recent version of the model: https://youtu.be/BD8wmlFCG6U  I know it looks even, but it isn't, there is still black hair showing and the hair on the scalp moves when animated because I had to increase the length in order for it to cover her entire head. Here is what it looked like before I messed with the hair particle settings and the guiding curves: https://youtu.be/TipDNkmpLGM

Answer (score 4):

### Combine a Short Hairstyle with a Dynamic Ponytail

Since the main hair doesn't move, but only the ponytail, you can **leave the main hair static** and make only the **ponytail dynamic** (plus dynamic bangs, and another layer of fly-off hair if you want more realism.) It's like a hair extension and fairly easy to do.

[image: turnaround of the ponytail hairstyle]

<sup>Turnaround of the ponytail hairstyle</sup>

**Preparation**

- create a little cylinder or "ring" (it's more a disc). It will be the emitter for the ponytail. I've added a *Torus* object (`12` major, `8` minor segments), deleted the inner faces, and grid-filled the hole.

[image: Ponytail emitter ring]
<sup>Ponytail hair emitter ("ring")</sup>

- place this ponytail emitter ("ring") behind the head where you want to have the ponytail
- **Important**! **Apply the scale** to the "ring" and the head because a lot of the hair settings are relative to the emitter's size. You will get weird-looking results in the simulation and in Cycles renderings. Eevee is more error-tolerant.

**Create and Comb the Main Hair**

**Note:** The main hair is on a haircap/scalp emitter. The head is a separate object and is bald. All objects have real-world size.

- add a *Hair Particle System* to the haircap/scalp. `500` particles, `8` segments are fine. You can increase/reduce the number of segments in Particle Edit mode (menu *Particle → Rekey*; particles must be selected.)
- Comb the hair. Select the lower hair (everything at the level of the ears in front view, box select) and comb it up in the direction to the "ring". Tighten the strand of hair guides and try to pull them through the ring.
- at the front of the head, pull the hair gently back so the children can't accidentally disappear inside the head (bald spots!)
- when you're finished, cut all hair particles (guides) behind the ring.
- repeat the combing for the side parts, then for the back top, and finally for the bangs (if you want a parting)
- try to layer the hair parts
- don't forget you can hide combed parts of the hair so it gets not messed up by further edits. You also can select the roots (menu) and select more segments (keys) with <kbd>Numbpad</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to easily select single hair guides and comb them.

**Create the Ponytail**

- select the "ring", in *Edit Mode*, select the inner faces, and assign them to a Vertex Group "Ponytail" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). This is where the ponytail will grow.
- assign material for the hair ("Ponytail" group) and another material for the outside of the ring (inverted selection)
- add a *Hair Particle System* to the ring emitter, `500` particles, `26cm`, `8` segments
- use the created Vertex Group "Ponytail" in *Particle Properties → Vertext Groups → Density* so the hair grows "through" the ring and not on the outside of the ring.
- enable *Particle Properties → [X] Hair Dynamics*, in section *Hair Dynamics → Structure* increase the random value (`0.422`). This widens the ponytail a little
- Note: the values for *Vertex Mass* and *Stiffness* have an effect on the stiffness but I left them at the default settings and just did a little weight painting.

[image: weight paint the ponytail]

<sup>Weight paint of the ponytail</sup>

- in *Particle Edit* mode, weight paint the keys (black dots) a little, see screenshot. This spreads the ponytail somewhat, makes it fluffy and it doesn't look completely flat from the side.
- run the animation. In about 60 frames the ponytail should have fallen down nicely. It should neither sap off nor stick out.

[image: simulated ponytail]

<sup>Simulated hair dynamics of the ponytail</sup>

**Tweak the Hair Particle Settings**

- *Children*, select `Interpolated`, amount: `80`. For the ponytail only: Length: `0.959`, Threshold: `0.306`. It makes the end of the ponytail a little more shaggy.
- adjust the values for *Clumping*, *Roughness*, and *Kink* as you like.
- use a small number for *Roughness → Random*, like `0.021`
- if the children of the main hair try to overgrow the ring emitter then try to increase Clumping → Clump a bit, e.g. `0.479`
- `Kink` works well for the ponytail (used `Wave` in the example) but select a small *Amplitude* like `0.02 m` so it doesn't "explode"
- for *Hair Shape* use values like *Strand Shape*: `-0.9`, *Diameter Root*: `0.03`, *Tip*: `0.01`, *Diameter Scale*: `0.01` (default). **These values are important for Cycles** if you don't want to have super fat hair particles.

**Animation test:**

[image: animated ponytail]

Comment: This didn't work for me. The Torus won't attach to the rest of the model and looks terrible.

Comment: In a static way or when it's animated?

Comment: Both static and animated unfortunately. I tried joining vertices but it messes with the rest of the mesh. I also have the hardest time layering  the hair because the guiding curves are too strong even when I adjust the radius, but that's a separate issue. I'll add a picture later today. The good news is that this method got me closer to the hair I wanted to make.

Comment: I couldn't post a picture, but here is a video: https://youtu.be/9lyFOFBZM4s

Comment: sorry for the late response. You can increase the number of segments so that the hair can be combed better. You can change the number of segments at any time via Rekey if you select the hair guides beforehand.